# add-text-properties throws args out of range

Tags: text-properties

I have a reasonably large buffer, whose first five characters i like to make as comment (this is a simplified problem of a larger issue, so bear with me).

Buffer contents:

```
;;some comment text, whose property needs to be changed.
(add-text-properties 0 7 
                     '(comment t face highlight))
```

When i do `eval-buffer`, it throws error as, `Args out of range: 0, 7`.

Since the buffer has more than five characters, why does `add-text-properties` throw out of range error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first point in the buffer is **1**, not **0** -- that is why the example produces an error message stating **Args out of range . . .**.  The doc-string for `add-text-properties` states that START and END are buffer positions, unless the optional argument OBJECT is a string.  Since there is no optional OBJECT argument in the example, we are dealing with strictly buffer positions.

The first line of code, `(ignore "hello" "bye" "chalo")`, serves no purpose and detracts from the issue.

```
add-text-properties is a built-in function in `C source code'.

(add-text-properties START END PROPERTIES &optional OBJECT)

Add properties to the text from START to END.
The third argument PROPERTIES is a property list
specifying the property values to add.  If the optional fourth argument
OBJECT is a buffer (or nil, which means the current buffer),
START and END are buffer positions (integers or markers).
If OBJECT is a string, START and END are 0-based indices into it.
Return t if any property value actually changed, nil otherwise.
```

Comment: changed the sample code to be simpler... thanks, lawlist..